# Rendering an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to render [this array of objects](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.fe569654581346d9a97ebfea58bf219a&right=local.ranebu) . I keep getting this error:
`TypeError: _this.state.dataSource.map is not a function`
when I try to map the state holding the array.

An example:

```
<View>
{this.state.dataSource.map(item => <Text>{item.full_name}</Text>}
</View>
```

Comment: Sounds like `this.state.dataSource` is not actually an array. Try `console.log`-ing it to make sure it's the type that you expect.

Comment: @SumnerEvans Yes, you are correct. I forgot to use JSON.parse() to change it back into an object it was a string.

Answer (score 0):

Probably is trying to iterate over this.state.dataSource and it is undefined.

```
<View>
{this.state.dataSource?.length > 0 && this.state.dataSource.map(item => <Text>{item.full_name}</Text>}
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reason because of which you are getting that error. Maybe the dataSource is being used before it was initialised.

First step, you must add a check if the dataSource array is valid or not.

Second Step, make sure that your dataSource does not have any data that you dont want, it could be an object.

Third, make sure that you parse your data to JSON after it's fetched from the source.